# Cannot Access Memory Adress at error when trying to access a shared data array with pthreads

Tags: c++, debugging, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I have a pthread program with two threads. First thread writes to Array[0 - 196607] and second thread writes to Array[196608 - 393215].

I am getting a "Cannot Access Memory at address ..." error when accessing Array elements [33779 through 393215]. because of this I am getting a segfault. Can someone please help me how to proceed debugging this issue?

Next question I have is, when my threads are writing to different address locations of the same array, do I need to use a lock on them?

relevant code is

contents of main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.cpp"


int *array;

int main() {
   array = new int[393216];
   foo(array);
   return 0;
}
```

contents of a.cpp

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct a {
   int array[];
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *funcname (void* param) {
    struct a *data = (struct a*) param;
    int index = 33779;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    data->array[index] = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}


void foo (int array[]) {
    struct a* data[2];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    pthread_t threads[2];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i) {
        data[i] = (struct a*)malloc (sizeof(struct a));
        *data[i]->array = *array;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);

        pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, funcname, data[i]);

    }
    for ( int i = 0 ; i< 2; ++i)
        pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We'll need to see some code please.

Comment: You *have* allocated enough memory for your data?

Comment: @joe: Just updated the question with the code. Thank you

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: yes I have.

Comment: Your code example should be simple, compilable and demonstrate your problem. Merely getting an example together like that can help you find your own problem sometimes too! :-)

Comment: I just checked that all elements of the array are accessible within main, after the ` new array[ ] ` line. However the elements[33779 - 393215] are not accessible when I try to access data->array[33779] after the line `*data[i]->array = *array`. Strangely, at the same place array[33779] is accessible.

Comment: You have lot of typo in your example which make compilation/run fails. array and data are uninitialized, 'struct a' vs 'struct v', you didn't delete[] array, int main should return. Once fixed, for your problem, * data[i]->array = * array copy only the first element (so 'struct a' should be struct a {int * array}; and then data[i]->array = array),

Comment: @joe just made the code compilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*data[i]->array = *array;
```

just copy the first element.
you may use

```
struct a { int* array; }
```

and then, just copy the pointer.

```
data[i]->array = array;
```